# Request from client to server with data from both <form> elements and javascript in struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

This is my jsp file

```
<script>
    var object = "I'm object";
</script>

<s:form action="requesting" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="name" key="label.name" />
    <s:submit method="execute" key="label.submit">
</s:form>
```

I want to get these javascript object("object") and form propertiy("name") in action class.
How to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it in some hidden field to include then on form post, or make ajax call